# How to get location using Geolocator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

code that  has been used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    try {
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
   } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold();
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Waiting for AOSP on IA Emulator to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51964/UEmjv7haU5w=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
I/Choreographer(14504): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(14504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8804b00: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea15ec70)
D/eglCodecCommon(14504): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
I/OpenGLRenderer(14504): Davey! duration=2865ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=25791957327046, Vsync=25793890660302, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=25793896676340, AnimationStart=25793898368240, PerformTraversalsStart=25793934314440, DrawStart=25794433733640, SyncQueued=25794660799440, SyncStart=25794663501440, IssueDrawCommandsStart=25794663679640, SwapBuffers=25794747224740, FrameCompleted=25794825369240, DequeueBufferDuration=32086000, QueueBufferDuration=859000, 
D/EGL_emulation(14504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe88045c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea15e5e0)
D/eglCodecCommon(14504): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/flutter (14504): The location service on the device is disabled.
```

Comment: Did you give permission in manifest file for location ?

Comment: yes, i have asked it for permission in emulator     code -  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score 1):

Your output says "The location service on the device is disabled" so may you should check the permission in the manifest file. I suggest you to use the coarse and fine permissions together.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

But you should make a previous verification of the location service too before do geolocation-requests.

you should chechk if the service is enabled:

```dart
bool isLocationServiceEnabled  = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
print('location enabled: $isLocationServiceEnabled');
```

then check if the app has permissions:

```dart
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
print(permission);
```

if you don't have permissions ask for them:

```dart
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
print(permission);
```

with all that set up you can make a secure request

```dart
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
print(position);
```

Comment: okay now i tried this and this is what its saying
'I/flutter (15589): location enabled: true
I/flutter (15589): LocationPermission.denied
I/flutter (15589): LocationPermission.always
I/flutter (15589): The location service on the device is disabled.'

Comment: ok, so you dont have permissions for location, you should try to reinstall the app to see if it ask for permission. If it doesn't work you could use this plugin to manage permission https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler . But, if u want to see results inmediatly you can go to the cellphone config->apps->ur app->permissions and enable location permission there, then u can use the 2nd plugin to avoid this type of problems in the future.

Comment: I reinstalled the app just as u said and looked into apps permission, location services for this app is enabled, but still no change in output

Comment: well, i was reading the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and 1st it says that it just requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. 2nd you have to check in the notification bar if location is enabled 3rd at right go to 'more', at location tab mark a place and set location to see if it works 4th try with a real device, too much times it happens with the emulator, they don't work with location flutter codes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the codes :

```
var geolocator = Geolocator();
var locationOptions;


getPermission() async {
return Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();
}
```

then call this function in initState() :

```
getPermission().then((res) {
  locationOptions =
      LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);
});

 geolocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    lat = position.latitude.toDouble();
    long = position.longitude.toDouble();
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah it works thanks but its not stopping , keeps printing latitude and longitude again and again.

Comment: because it's a stream and returns changed location. if you want a location, you can use this code:   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

Comment: if you above where i have asked this question, I have used this code that you just written and thats why I posted that I am not getting the location out of this code.